# Why doesn't numba optimize subroutines called in the code?

Tags: python, optimization, jit, numba

I'm new to numba and try using @jit to speed up a Python program, but this only affects my code. When my code calls another subroutine, it seems that this one is not getting optimized before execution.

Of course I could @jit decorate all functions, but this is limited when it comes to functions that I am only consuming (not having them developed myself).

See the following example based on the Leibniz formula for π.

```
def leibniz1(n):
    operand = 1.0
    result = 0.0
    for i in xrange(1, n*2, 2):
        result += operand / i
        operand = - operand
    return result * 4
```

Runtime for leibniz1(10000000): approx. 0.8 seconds

When I add

```
from numba import jit, int32
```

and decorate the function with @jit

```
@jit
def leibniz2(n):
    operand = 1.0
    result = 0.0
    for i in xrange(1, n*2, 2):
        result += operand / i
        operand = - operand
    return result * 4
```

Runtime for 10000000 iterations reduces to approx. 0.1 seconds.

The problem comes here:

```
@jit
def leibniz3(n):
     return leibniz1(n)
```

I would expect that leibniz3 is getting optimized, and so is leibniz1 - because it is called from the optimized function. But that's not the case, runtime is again approx. 0.8 seconds, that's the pure leibniz1 value.

**Is there a chance to achieve my plan with numba or something similar, because I cannot @jit decorate all functions my program is relying on, because they are not from me.**

Comment: First - Numba only supports (in a way that will accelerate) a fairly restrictive range of Python, so if you don't have access to the functions you may find you can't make it work too well. Second, you can always do `jitted_function = numba.jit(<insert optional signature>)(some_other_module.function)` [- remember that a decorator is just a function call!] to jit functions that you didn't write.

Answer (score 1):

First I recommend to use the nopython argument:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def f(x):
    ....
```

This way you force the C/Fortran like compilation of your functions and you get an explicit error if it fails in doing so.
From the [Documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.35.0/user/jit.html):

> Numba has two compilation modes: nopython mode and object mode. The former produces much faster code, but has limitations that can force Numba to fall back to the latter. To prevent Numba from falling back, and instead raise an error, pass nopython=True.

Also in the documentation it is stated:

> The @jit decorator must be added to any such library function, otherwise Numba may generate much slower code.

Basically your problem is the same as if you wanted to call a function from a high level language in pure C/Fortran.
So unfortunately as far as I know, there is no other solution than to reimplement the other functions in your close-to-the-machine code.